# How to create a new document in Couchbase?

Tags: ios, objective-c, couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-view

Anyone who know how to create a new document in Couchbase iOS implementation?

Step 1: Create Couchbase Buckets
Step 2: Create Document

What next step?

Please see attached.

[image: Couchbase Buckets]

[image: Create Document]

Please look at the documents I wanted to add:
Screen shots follows,

[[image: User]]

[[image: Information]]

[[image: Filter]]

[[image: Chat]]

[[image: Broadcast]]

[[image: Notification]]

[[image: Comments]]

[[image: Blocked_user]]

[[image: Location]]

[[image: Like]]

[[image: Reach]]

Comment: In which language are you trying to implement this? The [docs](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.3/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/document/index.html) might be helpful.

Comment: @Kyriakos Objective C :)

Comment: Your screen shot appears to show the Couchbase Server console.  This is completely different from Couchbase Lite, which is what you'd use for iOS.  Look at the docs Kyriakos links to, or try starting [here](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/).  Also, you might want to edit your original post to remove what looks like your real email address.

Answer (score 0):

The (Swift) answer is

```
let properties = [
    "type": "person",
    "name": "frank",
    "created_at": "some timestamp"
]
let doc = database.createDocument()
do {
    return try doc.putProperties(properties)
} catch let error as NSError {
    handleError(error)
    return nil
}
```

or obj-C

```
NSDictionary* properties = @{@"type": @"person",
                             @"name": @"frank",
                             @"created_at": @"some timestamp"};
CBLDocument* doc = [database createDocument];
NSError* error;
if (![doc putProperties: properties error: &error]) {
    [self handleError: error];
}
```

The guide is pretty good and walks you though a lot of the getting started process.

[Using the Database](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.3/develop/training/using-the-database/index.html)